# Bank account number and Sort Code in a form

Tags: security

I am creating a Finance form for a small car finance company using Wordpress. However a potential customer needs to be able to enter his bank account number and bank sort code into the form along with his name and address details. The form is then sent to the owner of the finance company.

My question is what is the best way to keep this information secure.

I was going to use an SSL certificate and perhaps a wordpress plugin like WP PGP, but I do not know if this would be secure and also if there are any legal problems with doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: No one can tell you about legal without even knowing which country are you in, and even then it's probably not a good idea. You need to research legal obligations on this before any tech is decided on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like bad news. There are many technical and legal hurdles involved in collecting bank info online. It is easy to mess up.

All SSL does is protect information in transit between a browser (person filling the form) and the server.

Once it gets to the server you need to handle it properly. If you plan to use a common form plugin, the info will most likely get stored in your DB or emailed as plain text; **that's bad**. I'd be sceptical of encryption plugins as well unless they were audited, even then you may have another rouge plugin that can cause issues.

I'd start by looking into the following:

- Your local/national  regulatory requirements
- Where the bank info goes after the owner get's it. Is it a third party? Do they offer a secure API or portal you can leverage?
- [PCI compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). Even though you probably don't fall into its scope they can give you an idea of how this type of information is handled